# Switch Statement with Button pressed

Tags: android, button, view, switch-statement

So I push either button1, button2, button3, or button4.  Pushing any of these Buttons calls method buttonPressed(View v).  I want to use a different case depending on the button pressed.  For example:

```
public void buttonPressed(View v){
switch(v){
case button1:
//do something
case button2:
//do something
case button3:
//do something
case button4:
//do something
}}
```

Obviously, this does not work.  I cannot use a switch statement with a View.  What is the easiest and most efficient solution to this problem?  Thanks!!

*Note:  I am using android:onClick="buttonPressed" in my .xml*

Comment: I dont know if you are using this in a library project, but this is good to know just in case : http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch on the View's ID, not the View itself

```
public void buttonPressed(View v){
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ButtonOneID:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonTwoID:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonThreeID:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.ButtonFourID:
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Evorlor it will be an integer

Answer (score 2):

```
public void buttonPressed(View v){
    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id){
    case button1.getId();
        //do something
        break;
    case button2.getId();
        //do something
        break;
    case button3.getId();
        //do something
        break;
    case button4.getId();
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `button1.getId()` not  `button.getId()`